# What is the meaning of 'N-PLURAL' in the Collins COBUILD dictionary?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech, dictionaries, acronyms

N-PLURAL represents plural noun according to the explanation in the Collins COBUILD dictionary. Can I interpret it as a noun that is countable but unable to be used in singular form and only able to be used in plural form?  [image]

Comment: This could easily have been added to the first question. Also, I don't think a clear, correct, definitive answer has been given to the first one yet.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries should usually include a usage guide that explains what things like *N-PLURAL* mean, but yes, your guess is basically correct.  *Trousers* is one of the nouns in English that can really only be used in a plural form:

> He wore trousers

Never

> He wore *a trouser*

There are a few words like this: trousers, pants, scissors, clothes, glasses (but only when it means "reading glasses" - drinking glasses can be singular).  These words are technically called [plurale tantum](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/05/12-nouns-that-are-always-plurals/).

Comment: There are many usages of ***a scissor*** as a noun.  Check out [Google books](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&client=ms-android-verizon&ei=rtepV97CNYPLmwGU86NY&q="a+scissor"+&oq="a+scissor"+&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3..41j0l2j0i22i30l2.3682.6472.0.7135.5.4.1.0.0.0.307.861.0j2j1j1.4.0....0...1c.1j4.64.mobile-gws-serp..1.4.736.j14nIVG2Vrg#q=%22a+scissor%22&safe=strict&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&tbm=bks) for 21st century uses only. It's also used earlier (20th century, etc).

Comment: OK, scissors isn't **always** plural...[just the vast majority of the time, including historically](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+scissor%2Cscissors&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20scissor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscissors%3B%2Cc0).  For the learner of English, I would say that a pretty good first approximation is that *scissors* is always plural.